# Could not upload photo using IFormFile object in ASP.Net Core 2 with null reference expception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi, iformfile

I tried to upload a photo using `IFormFile` using a postman plugin. But the API didn't get the file object from the body of the request. I tried with and without `[FromBody]`.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(int vId, IFormFile fileStream)
{
    var vehicle = await this.repository.GetVehicle(vId, hasAdditional: false);
    if (vehicle == null)
        return NotFound();
    var uploadsFolderPath = Path.Combine(host.WebRootPath, "uploads");
    if (!Directory.Exists(uploadsFolderPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadsFolderPath);
    var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(fileStream.FileName);
    var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolderPath, fileName);

    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await fileStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }
```

The [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Iutc.png) shows on this line :

> ```
>     var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(fileStream.FileName);
> ```

I figured out that it is not getting the file, while I am sending an image.jpg with the same key `"fileStream"`. By the way everything else works fine. I found no solution to fix this issue. If anybody can help me with this please let me know.

[image]

Comment: Please debug your project. Is `fileStream` really null? Can you look at the `Request` object to see what data is being received? You should be able to see what fields the posted form actually contains. Also check with [Postman’s dev tools](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/debugging_and_logs) to see what the actual request is that is being sent there.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  It was null somehow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally got the solution. Actually the problem was with the old version of postman Tabbed Postman - REST Client chrome extension. After trying with new postman app it worked perfectly fine. Thanks all of you who tried to solve this problem. Here is the result:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5FQZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The **FromBody** attribute can only be used on one parameter in the signature.
One option to send the `int vId` is by a query string and read it with the **FromQuery** attribute.

Try it like this

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromQuery]int vId, [FromBody]IFormFile fileStream)
```

Then make the POST to url `api/yourController?vId=123456789` where the body contains the **IFromFile**

**Update**

As the form-data will be sent as key-value try and create a model containing the keys and read it from the body

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public IFormFile fileStream { get; set; }
}
```

Then read the model from the body

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromBody]RequestModel model)
```

Comment: Actually I passed the vId in the url. That's fine. Just not getting the IFormFile from the body. See in the image.

Comment: @RobinKhan have you tried with just Upload(IFormFile fileStream) ?

Comment: I checked that if the fileStream object sending form the formbody in the post was null or not. If that was null then I send a bad request saying null file. I don't know why it is getting null while I am sending an image file with the same key "fileStream" similar in the parameter.